# ReportingService Integration with Java and NetBeans

Tags: java, soap, reporting-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have the following problem. I try to consume soap services in java from SSRS, for this, I use the web services assistant that comes with netbeans (jax-ws (web services client)). Once I have the classes generated in my project, I try to make the session start with the logonuser method (name, pass, auth).

```
ReportExecutionService service = new ReportExecutionService();
ReportExecutionServiceSoap rs = service.getReportExecutionServiceSoap();

try {
     rs.logonUser("Administrator", "Passw0rd!!", "EVALAB01\\");
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.LogonUser(String userName, String password, String authority)
```

I am really sure the user name and password are correct, since they are the same I used to make the connection with the NetBeans assistance (Web Services Client), and I am also sure that's the domain name, so I can't see what exactly is causing the error. I also tried with many changes on the domain name, adding and taking out the \, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are good for the domain you specify, do you need to be specifying the domain?

Comment: I need to use java for integration. But, i do not have any error when i did that same example in C# and i used the same credentials.

Comment: Also, when the domain does not exist, the name of the computer must have been specified